# Heroku nodejs can not post data

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a simple nodejs api, which connected to mongodb on mlab.

On local I can use GET, POST methods. But after I deployed to Heroku:
I only GET data. 
POST method returns 400 bad request. And if I use `heroku logs -t` I can't see log about `post` method.

I searched related keywords: `heroku -nodejs- post method 400 bad request`, they don't work with my case.

This is my log after I use `postman` send GET and POST requests.

```
2020-04-01T16:58:02.831314+00:00 app[web.1]: tiny wiz running                      // my console.log
2020-04-01T16:58:03.131550+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-04-01T16:58:03.259355+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
2020-04-01T16:58:27.099916+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=MYAPP_URL request_id=a5f384ad-b857-4356-a4de-f8148cfd2e16 fwd="publicIP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=100ms status=200 bytes=1016 protocol=https
2020-04-01T16:58:27.094337+00:00 app[web.1]: GET METHOD HERE!!!                   // my console.log
 ▸    Log stream timed out. Please try again.
```

As you can see, It has no log about `POST` method.

Pls let's me know if you has any infomation about my environment.

Thank in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

Comment: @jualahmed I think status code is not my problem.

My app works on local. And on Heroku, it has no log about POST method.

I think I need check Heroku's setting(maybe)